# JCaptcha failed when cookie is blocked

Tags: java, cookies, captcha

I have implemented JCaptcha in my web application and it works fine but when cookies of the browser is blocked it always fail and return false.

the servlet code is as follows:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



        String userCaptchaResponse =request.getParameter("jcaptcha");
        boolean captchaPassed = SimpleImageCaptchaServlet.validateResponse(request, userCaptchaResponse);

        if(captchaPassed){
        System.out.println("success!!"+userCaptchaResponse);
        RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Result.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

        //response.sendRedirect("Result.jsp");

        }else{
            System.out.println("failure!!"+userCaptchaResponse);
            response.sendRedirect("Index.jsp"+"?id=false");

        }

    }
```

and code in jsp page is

```
<tr align="center">
<td align="right" width="33%"><img height="60px" width="140px" src="jcaptcha.jpg" /></td>
<td align="left" width="33%" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="jcaptcha" value="" /></td>
</tr>
```

I want my captcha to work irrespective of whether the cookies are blocked or not!!!
is there any solution for this or any other method to implement captcha in java 
I am using jdk 1.7 and tomcat 7 as runtime environment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your captcha lookup is that it relies on a User session. Which is in my opinion a design flaw. If cookies are blocked the session will not be linked to the user.

There are other libraries e.g. [SimpleCatcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/). Or other services like [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

Basically if you have a library which generates you a captcha you might implement it like this as pseudo algorithm which is not session dependent:

For every form including a captcha:

- Generate temporary captcha
- Generate a hard to guess and unique identifier (maybe with a uuid).
- Link the unique identfier with the correct answer server side and persist it temporarily
- Provide the unique identifier in the generated form
- If a user sends the form he will provide the guess and the uuid you might lookup this pair on your server side.
- Invalidate the UUID and the Image wether or not the user entered the correct answer.

If this is too slow from a performance perspective you might consider to have a background process to fill up a fixed size FILO container/queue to hold precomputed captchas.

Answer (score 0):

JCaptcha doesn't work if the cookies are disabled. There is a bug: http://jcaptcha.octo.com/jira/browse/JASTR-3

You can try another library, for example recaptcha.